# Is Windows Power Management User Specific?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, power-management, powermanager

I'm working with windows power management APIs (`PowrProf.dll` P/Invokes) in C# to get and set power management settings of the system, but I'm not sure if the power management settings are user-specific or machine-specific :(

The flow for Windows XP is to get active power scheme (using `GetActivePwrScheme()`), read global power settings (using `ReadGlobalPwrPolicy()`), read scheme-specific settings (using `ReadPwrScheme()`) and if necessary, write the modified data back to system (using `SetActivePwrScheme()`).

The flow for windows vista and 7 is to get active power scheme (using `PowerGetActiveScheme()`), read individual power settings (using `PowerReadACValueIndex()` and `PowerReadDCValueIndex()`) and if necessary, write the modified data back to system (using `PowerWriteACValueIndex()` or `PowerWriteDCValueIndex()`).

The thing is I prefer to run these codes in a windows service and am afraid that if I run these I'll be getting and setting power management settings for the SYSTEM account. I'm a little bit confused, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As obvious as it sounds, I want to clarify that I have tested this from both a windows service and a windows application, the results were the same (or at least seemed completely similar to me) but I don't want to depend on guessing, I need something concrete and Microsoft doesn't seem to provide any hints on the issue :(

Comment: Really? No one knows?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching the Internet, finally I had to settle for the MSDN documentation. According to MSDN for XP we have :

[Global User Power Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : Contains global user power policy settings that apply to **all power schemes** for **a user**.

[Global Machine Power Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : Contains global computer power policy settings that apply to **all power schemes** for **all users**.

[User Power Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : Contains power policy settings that are unique to **each power scheme** for **a user**.

[Machine Power Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : Contains computer power policy settings that are unique to **each power scheme** on **the computer**.

And for Vista+, there are no global/local or user/machine settings; instead, everything is scheme specific and the settings apply to all users. ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

But when I tested aforementioned facts on two different machines (one running on Win XP and the other running on Win 7), I got unexpected results! On XP, running my code from a windows service (running as SYSTEM account) and a windows app (running as an administrator account) indicated no user-specific behavior. On Win7, the same experiment, created the same results!